# PIC16F877A ADC in assembly: Howto show result on 7 segment display

Tags: assembly, microcontroller, pic, seven-segment-display

I am trying to perform analog to digital conversion on PIC16f877a. well the problem is when I am showing my result on led it working fine but when I am showing my result on 7 segment I have some invalid output may be I am unable to convert binary to decimal properly **("for BCD conversion I am using 74ls47")** can any one help me.
Regards,
Haziq.

image is here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yCCR.png)

```
RES_VECT  CODE    0x0000            ; processor reset vector              
GOTO    START                   ; go to beginning of program           

; TODO ADD INTERRUPTS HERE IF USED              
CNT0    EQU 0x21 ;            

MAIN_PROG CODE                      ; let linker place main program         

START           

BSF STATUS,RP0         
MOVLW b'00000000'         
MOVWF TRISB         
MOVLW b'11110000'               
MOVWF TRISD            
MOVLW b'00000001'          
MOVWF TRISA              
BCF STATUS,5              

MAIN_LOOP          
CALL ADC_INIT ;INIT ADC MODULE          
CALL ADC_READ ;READ ANALOG VALUE AND STORE TO ANVAL REGISTER          

;OUTPUT ANVAL TO         
 ;==================================            
GOTO MAIN_LOOP               
;========================================================================================            
ADC_INIT       
BSF STATUS,RP0          ;SELECTING BANK 01 FOR ADCON1 REG           
MOVLW b'00001110'       ;LEFT JUSTIFIED, FOcs/8, +VREF=VDD, -VREF=VSS,          
AN0=ANALOG               
MOVWF ADCON1         
BCF STATUS,5            ;GOING BACK TO BANK 00         
MOVLW b'010000001'      ;FOcs/8, A0=ANALOG INPUT,             
MOVWF ADCON0              
RETURN           
;=========================================================================================              
ADC_READ               
BCF STATUS,5            ;SELECTING BANK 00              
BSF ADCON0, 2           ;START CONVERTION PROCESS (WE SET THE GO BIT)         
WAIT:      
BTFSC ADCON0, 2          
GOTO WAIT           ;WAIT FOR CONVERTION TO FINISH (WAIT FOR GO BIT TO CLEAR)             
MOVF ADRESH, W          ;MOVE ADRESH TO W           
MOVWF PORTB         ;SHOWING 8 MOST SIGNIFICANT BITS OF A/D RESULT         
MOVLW 0x06               
MOVWF CNT0              
AGAIN_0:               
BCF STATUS, C           ;WE WANT SHIFT (NOT ROTATE), SO WE CLEAR CARRY        
RLF ADRESL, 1           ;SHIFT LEFT 6 BITS A/D RESULT HIGH BYTE            
DECFSZ CNT0             
GOTO AGAIN_0                            
MOVF ADRESL, W          ;MOVE ADRESH TO W           
MOVWF PORTD         ;SHOWING 2 LEAST SIGNIFICANT BITS OF A/D RESULT          
RETURN              

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to do a HEX to BCD conversion in your software to get the BCD value for each digit.